# iOS array string in format 00:00:00 to array float in format 00.00.00 Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point, nsarray

I'm looking how to transform Array string to Array float, Array string is in format 00:00:00 (hh:mm:ss) and array float is 00.00.00 The reason is because array float Is calculated in a chart For now i only have this

```
example array
   TimeRunning = @[@"01:10:50", @"01:03:23", @"03:04:22"];//arrayStrig
```

real code is

```
timeRunning = [obj valueForKey:@"oficialTime"];
NSLog(@"%@",timeRunning); //out 01:02:03 10:10:02 10:38:59

float ofcTime =[[obj valueForKey:@"oficialTime"]floatValue];
NSLog(@"float : %f",ofcTime); //out 1.000000 10.000000 10.000000
```

I try this

```
NSString * dataString = [TimeRunningString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"."];
NSLog(@"??????: %@",dataString); //out 01.02.03  10.10.02  10.38.59

NSArray *listItems = [dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSLog(@"Real: %@",listItems);//out  10,
                                    10,
                                    02

NSString *covert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",listItems];
NSLog(@":%@",covert);   //out  10,
                               10,
                               02

float realArrary = [dataString floatValue];
NSLog(@"floatP : %f",realArrary); out 2.030000 10.000000 10.100000
```

Comment: convert nsstring to nsdate using NSdateFormatter. Now convert NSDate to miliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 NSString *dateString = [obj valueForKey:@"oficialTime"];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss.SSS"];
 NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
 dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
 NSLog(@"%@",dateString); //Out 02:03:03
```

then

```
NSString * dataString = [TimeRunningString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];             float Realarrary = [dataString floatValue];
NSLog(@"floatP: %0.0f",Realarrary); //Out 20303

 now you have string 02:03:03 to float 20303
```

Comment: Thank you Frank Villarroel  Is working can not give points but I will remember you  :)